# 64-bit WPF app silently crashes on startup on subset of computers

Tags: .net, wpf, 64-bit

I'm running into an obscure .NET (WPF) crash. My application, which is compiled with a platform target of 64-bit, silently crashes (no dialog or anything) and an event is logged in the Windows Event Viewer on a subset of my users' computers.

My application consists of the main WPF executable and a class library DLL, both compiled for the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and both with a target platform of 64-bit.

The weird thing is that if I compile the WPF executable with a target platform of Any CPU, but leave the class library with a target of 64-bit, then the application suddenly starts up fine.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
(a30.f0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!RtlPcToFileHeader+0x97:
00000000`7729ce6b 418b4350        mov     eax,dword ptr [r11+50h] ds:00000000`00000050=????????
0:000> k
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`004cefd0 000007fe`f1cecf00 ntdll!RtlPcToFileHeader+0x97
00000000`004cf050 000007fe`f1cece5d MSVCR110_CLR0400!__ExceptionPtr::_CopyException+0x8b
00000000`004cf140 000007fe`f1cec978 MSVCR110_CLR0400!__ExceptionPtr::_InitBadAllocException+0x5d
00000000`004cf1a0 000007fe`f1cf519b MSVCR110_CLR0400!IsProcessorFeaturePresent+0x1bfe
00000000`004cf1d0 000007fe`f1ced41f MSVCR110_CLR0400!initterm+0x1f
00000000`004cf200 000007fe`f1ced3bf MSVCR110_CLR0400!cinit+0x3f
00000000`004cf230 00000000`772cb0d8 MSVCR110_CLR0400!CrtEndBoot+0x65
00000000`004cf260 00000000`772b784a ntdll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines+0x1fe
00000000`004cf430 00000000`772b7b2e ntdll!LdrpLoadDll+0x231
00000000`004cf640 000007fe`fd9b9aa9 ntdll!LdrLoadDll+0x9a
00000000`004cf6b0 000007fe`fc24b05b KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW+0x22e
00000000`004cf720 000007fe`fc24aee3 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::LoadLibrary+0x193
00000000`004cf8a0 000007fe`fc242611 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::LoadMainRuntimeModule+0x266
00000000`004cf940 000007fe`fc24b2fb mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::EnsureLoaded+0x6a
00000000`004cf9d0 000007fe`fc24b299 mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::GetProcAddressInternal+0x23
00000000`004cfa00 000007fe`fc248974 mscoreei!CLRRuntimeInfoImpl::GetProcAddress+0x61
00000000`004cfa80 000007fe`fc2474c8 mscoreei!GetCorExeMainEntrypoint+0x120
00000000`004cfb40 000007fe`fb685b21 mscoreei!CorExeMain+0x41
00000000`004cfb90 00000000`76bc652d mscoree!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
00000000`004cfbc0 00000000`772bc521 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`004cfbf0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

This is obviously a big problem for me since it means I can't guarantee my application will actually run on an end-user's computer.

Has anybody run into something similar and know how to fix it? My application is loading 64-bit DLLs and I want to be absolutely sure it isn't running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Are you manually registering any exception handlers? It looks like your code is throwing a std::badalloc exception and then exploding when trying to find an exception handler to deal with it.

Comment: This is before any of my code runs, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Were you able to find anything that would work for this?  I experience something very similar.  It only happens on a couple of machines, which means we can't ship until we have solved this.